# JSX/React - Appending ListView Items

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Still wrapping my head around react and its mysterious ways. In jQuery + HTML one might have an element `<ListView> </ListView>` which is later populated by a for loop producing `<Item>`s. Equally in angular you would simply ng-repeat.

What is the react way to do this? I previously had this working when i had a `<ListView items={listItems}></ListView>` with listItems being defined elsewhere as `listItems = {heading:"qwerty", label:"test"}` etc but now when I inspect the code on execution i see that each `<Item>` created is a 'ReactElement' type and so using that behaviour is not supported.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Updated code:

```
render:function(){
    //Do the rendering

    var listViewItemsToRender = this.state.ListViewItems.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Item><div style={itemContainerParent}> <div style={itemPlatform}> <h1>props.platform</h1> </div><div style={routeInfo}><h1>props.routeInfo</h1></div><div style={timeInfo}><div style={row}><p>props.timeArriving</p></div><div style={row}><p>props.timeLeaving</p></div></div></div></Item>
        )
    });



    return (
        <Page>
            <BannerHeader theme="prime" key="header" flex={0} textAlign="center">Train Times</BannerHeader>
            <h2>{this.state.subheading}</h2>
            <Container>
                <Padding>
                    <BasicSegment>
                        <ButtonGroup fluid>
                            <Button onClick={this.showDepartures} variation={this.state.departuresSelected}>Departures</Button>
                            <Button onClick={this.showArrivals} variation={this.state.arrivalsSelected}>Arrivals</Button>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                        <Listview items={listViewItemsToRender}></Listview>

                    </BasicSegment>
                </Padding>
            </Container>
        </Page>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember in reactjs is uniderectional data flow. So you process data and the ui reacts based on your modifications...
So your render method would be the place to loop...

In your render handler method you would have a something like...

```
render : function(){
  return itemsTobeDisplayed = items.map(function(item){
      return yourCustomItemMethodWhichRendersAsingleItem(itm);
    });

}
```

Take a look at the reactjs todo exmple which show a list with single items

https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/react

...this might help.

Comment: Thank you! Just what i was after.

Comment: Updated my code to show what i thought i learned - this still doesn't work, items is still an array of ReactElements.

Comment: changing the line                             <Listview>{listViewItemsToRender}</Listview>
fixed it!

Comment: your are mixing now state and props. In your h1 you access props.routeInfo. this would be items.routeInfo. Where do you have your collection in state or in props? because you call map on this.state.ListViewItems..